# Spark - How to add an element to an array of structs

Tags: arrays, dataframe, apache-spark, struct, apache-spark-sql

Having this schema:

```
root
 |-- Elems: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Elem: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Desc: string (nullable = true)
```

**How can we add a new field** like that?

```
root
 |-- Elems: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- New_field: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Elem: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Desc: string (nullable = true)
```

I've already done that with a simple struct (more detail at the bottom of this post), but I'm not able to do it with an array of struct.

This is the code in order to test it:

```
val schema = new StructType()
    .add("Elems", ArrayType(new StructType()
        .add("Elem", IntegerType)
        .add("Desc", StringType)
    ))

val dataDS = Seq("""
{
  "Elems": [ {"Elem":1, "Desc": "d1"}, {"Elem":2, "Desc": "d2"}, {"Elem":3, "Desc": "d3"} ]
}
""").toDS()

val df = spark.read.schema(schema).json(dataDS.rdd)

df.show(false)
+---------------------------+
|Elems                      |
+---------------------------+
|[[1, d1], [2, d2], [3, d3]]|
+---------------------------+
```

Once we have the DF, the best approach I have is creating a Struct of arrays for each element:

```
val mod_df = df.withColumn("modif_elems", 
     struct(
         array(lit("")).as("New_field"),
         col("Elems.Elem"),
         col("Elems.Desc")
                            ))

mod_df.show(false)
+---------------------------+-----------------------------+
|Elems                      |modif_elems                  |
+---------------------------+-----------------------------+
|[[1, d1], [2, d2], [3, d3]]|[[], [1, 2, 3], [d1, d2, d3]]|
+---------------------------+-----------------------------+


mod_df.printSchema
root
 |-- Elems: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Elem: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Desc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- modif_elems: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- New_field: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = false)
 |    |-- Elem: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- Desc: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

We don't lose any data but this is not exactly what I want.

**Update**: Workaround in PD1.

---

## **Bonus track: Modifying a struct** (not in an array)

The code is almost the same but now we don't have an array of struct, so it's easier to modify the struct:

```
val schema = new StructType()
    .add("Elems", new StructType()
        .add("Elem", IntegerType)
        .add("Desc", StringType)
    )


val dataDS = Seq("""
{
  "Elems": {"Elem":1, "Desc": "d1"}
}
""").toDS()    


val df = spark.read.schema(schema).json(dataDS.rdd)
df.show(false)
+-------+
|Elems  |
+-------+
|[1, d1]|
+-------+

df.printSchema
root
 |-- Elems: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Elem: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Desc: string (nullable = true)
```

In this case, in order to add the field we need to create another struct:

```
val mod_df = df
    .withColumn("modif_elems", 
                struct(
                    lit("").alias("New_field"),
                    col("Elems.Elem"),
                    col("Elems.Desc")
                    )
               )

mod_df.show
+-------+-----------+
|  Elems|modif_elems|
+-------+-----------+
|[1, d1]|  [, 1, d1]|
+-------+-----------+

mod_df.printSchema
root
 |-- Elems: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Elem: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Desc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- modif_elems: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- New_field: string (nullable = false)
 |    |-- Elem: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Desc: string (nullable = true)
```

---

### PD1:

Ok, I have used [arrays_zip](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@arrays_zip(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) Spark SQL function (new in 2.4.0 version) and it's nearly what I want but I can't see how we can change the elements names (*as* or *alias* doesn't work here):

```
val mod_df = df.withColumn("modif_elems", 
        arrays_zip(
            array(lit("")).as("New_field"),
            col("Elems.Elem").as("Elem"),
            col("Elems.Desc").alias("Desc")
                    )
        )

mod_df.show(false)
+---------------------------+---------------------------------+
|Elems                      |modif_elems                      |
+---------------------------+---------------------------------+
|[[1, d1], [2, d2], [3, d3]]|[[, 1, d1], [, 2, d2], [, 3, d3]]|
+---------------------------+---------------------------------+

mod_df.printSchema
root
 |-- Elems: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Elem: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Desc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- modif_elems: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- 0: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- 1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- 2: string (nullable = true)
```

Struct *modif_elems* shoud contains 3 elements named *New_field*, *Elem* and *Desc*, not *0*, *1* and *2*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Spark 3.1+**

[**`withField`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#withField(fieldName:String,col:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) can be used (together with [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#transform(column:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,f:org.apache.spark.sql.Column=%3Eorg.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column))

- **Scala**

  Input:

  ```scala
  val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq((1, "2")))
      .select(
          array(struct(
              col("_1").as("Elem"),
              col("_2").as("Desc")
          )).as("Elems")
      )
  df.printSchema()
  // root
  //  |-- Elems: array (nullable = true)
  //  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
  //  |    |    |-- Elem: integer (nullable = true)
  //  |    |    |-- Desc: string (nullable = true)
  ```

  Script

  ```scala
  val df2 = df.withColumn(
      "Elems",
      transform(
          $"Elems",
          x => x.withField("New_field", lit(3))
      )
  )
  df2.printSchema()
  // root
  //  |-- Elems: array (nullable = false)
  //  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
  //  |    |    |-- Elem: long (nullable = true)
  //  |    |    |-- Desc: string (nullable = true)
  //  |    |    |-- New_field: integer (nullable = false)
  ```
- **PySpark**

  Input:

  ```py
  from pyspark.sql import functions as F
  df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, "2",)]) \
      .select(
          F.array(F.struct(
              F.col("_1").alias("Elem"),
              F.col("_2").alias("Desc")
          )).alias("Elems")
      )
  df.printSchema()
  # root
  #  |-- Elems: array (nullable = true)
  #  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
  #  |    |    |-- Elem: integer (nullable = true)
  #  |    |    |-- Desc: string (nullable = true)
  ```

  Script:

  ```py
  df = df.withColumn(
      "Elems",
      F.transform(
          F.col("Elems"),
          lambda x: x.withField("New_field", F.lit(3))
      )
  )
  df.printSchema()
  # root
  #  |-- Elems: array (nullable = false)
  #  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
  #  |    |    |-- Elem: long (nullable = true)
  #  |    |    |-- Desc: string (nullable = true)
  #  |    |    |-- New_field: integer (nullable = false)
  ```

Answer (score 3):

**Solution** here. We need to do use arrays_zip and then rename the obtained column with the renamed schema of the struct (`elem_struct_recomposed`):

```
val elem_struct_recomposed = new StructType()
  .add("New_field", StringType)
  .add("ElemRenamed", IntegerType)
  .add("DescRenamed", StringType)


val mod_df = df
    .withColumn("modif_elems_NOT_renamed", 
        arrays_zip(
            array(lit("")).as("New_field"),
            col("Elems.Elem").as("ElemRenamed"),
            col("Elems.Desc").alias("DescRenamed")
                    ))
    .withColumn("modif_elems_renamed", 
               $"modif_elems_NOT_renamed".cast(ArrayType(elem_struct_recomposed)))


mod_df.show(false)
mod_df.printSchema

+---------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|Elems                      |modif_elems_NOT_renamed          |modif_elems_renamed              |
+---------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|[[1, d1], [2, d2], [3, d3]]|[[, 1, d1], [, 2, d2], [, 3, d3]]|[[, 1, d1], [, 2, d2], [, 3, d3]]|
+---------------------------+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+

root
 |-- Elems: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Elem: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Desc: string (nullable = true)
 |-- modif_elems_NOT_renamed: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- 0: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- 1: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- 2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- modif_elems_renamed: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- New_field: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- ElemRenamed: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- DescRenamed: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Hello @rvilla, how can we use arrays_zip on Spark 2.3? any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I did not try it, but you could implement the functions as you can see in the github source code:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala

Take note that `ArraysZip` is a case class from `org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/collectionOperations.scala`. You could see it properly using your favourite code editor and opening the `arrays_zip` function source code.

Comment: @rvilla for spark 2.3 please see my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61919972/how-to-handle-missing-nested-fields-in-spark/61924562#61924562

Comment: This method produces nulls in the "New_Field" if "Elems" column has more than 1 element

Comment: What is `elem_struct_recomposed`?

Comment: Sorry sohil, I forgot to specify the renamed schema of the struct. Fixed (I just tested it on a local Spark 3.1.2 with no problems). Thanks!