# How to handle missing nested fields in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given the two case classes:

```
case class Response(
  responseField: String
  ...
  items: List[Item])

case class Item(
  itemField: String
  ...)
```

I am creating a `Response` dataset:

```
val dataset = spark.read.format("parquet")
                .load(inputPath)
                .as[Response]
                .map(x => x)
```

The issue arises when `itemField` is not present in any of the rows and spark will raise this error `org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No such struct field itemField`. If `itemField` was not nested I could handle it by doing `dataset.withColumn("itemField", lit(""))`. Is it possible to do the same within the `List` field?

Comment: I tried to replicate this issue without success. could you please add an example with sample data?

Comment: Any case where the specific field is not part of the data at all and therefore is not recognized in the schema.
`{ "responseField": "1", "items": [ {"otherField": "1"}] } { "responseField": "2", "items": [ {"otherField": "2"}] }`.
`itemField` is missing and therefore the encoding to the case classes does not work. 
A real life scenario: Extending a kafka event with a new field and making the aggregation pipeline work with it. Aggregations based on old events that do not have the field will be broken. @NoamShaish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the following:

Data was written with the following schema:

```scala
case class Item(itemField: String)
case class Response(responseField: String, items: List[Item])
Seq(Response("a", List()), Response("b", List())).toDF.write.parquet("/tmp/structTest")
```

Now schema changed to:

```scala
case class Item(itemField: String, newField: Int)
case class Response(responseField: String, items: List[Item])
spark.read.parquet("/tmp/structTest").as[Response].map(x => x) // Fails
```

For Spark 2.4 please see: 
[Spark - How to add an element to an array of structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54188311/spark-how-to-add-an-element-to-an-array-of-structs)

For Spark 2.3 this should work:

```scala
val addNewField: (Array[String], Array[Int]) => Array[Item] = (itemFields, newFields) => itemFields.zip(newFields).map { case (i, n) => Item(i, n) }

val addNewFieldUdf = udf(addNewField)
spark.read.parquet("/tmp/structTest")
   .withColumn("items", addNewFieldUdf(
      col("items.itemField") as "itemField", 
      array(lit(1)) as "newField"
   )).as[Response].map(x => x) // Works
```